# I want to retrieve a set of results for each object within an array in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have an array defined. I want to Select two different results for each object within the defined array, but I can't figure it out. I want to pull Name and Email address for each object (which is a username) from the array.

[image: screenshot of syntax and error]

I tried this, and was expecting a result of two lines, each line containing the Name and EmailAddress for each object within the array.

[image: powershell lines]

Comment: Please, [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557), see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Get-ADUser documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-filter), the `-Filter` parameter doesn't accept arrays, so you'll either have to run the command for each user, or with no username provided and then filter to select the users you want, like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Properties * | where Name -in $array
```

Keep in mind, though, this will pull all users first before filtering it down. So if you have a large number of users it could take some time.

Another issue is in the second line, you're using `@array` instead of `$array`. This drastically changes the behavior, and it's not what you want. Make sure to use `$array`.

Lastly, the `-ExpandProperty` parameter can only take one property name, whereas you're passing two (Name & EmailAddress). If you omit `-ExpandProperty`, it should return something like this:

```
PS C:\Users\alex28> Get-ADUser -Properties * | where Name -in $array | Select Name, EmailAddress
Name   EmailAddress
----   ------------
alex28 alex28@gmail.com
beth19 beth19@gmail.com
```

Comment: Oh, duh, makes sense about the $.

Now I see this error, however:

Get-ADUser : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser' required by
parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:12
+ get-aduser $array -properties * | Select Name, EmailAddress
+            ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: Looking at the [Get-ADUser documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-filter), the `-Filter` parameter doesn't accept arrays, so you'll either have to do one username at a time, or provide no username so it pulls all users, then filter the users you want. I've updated the answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

[`-Identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-identity) parameter from `Get-ADUser` only takes an `ADUser` as input, and an [`ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.aduser?view=activedirectory-management-10.0) can be constructed from:

- A distinguished name
- A GUID (objectGUID)
- A security identifier (objectSid)
- A SAM account name (sAMAccountName)

Passing an array as input to this parameter is not valid, however an easy workaround since this parameter takes pipeline input:

```bash
$array = 'alex', 'beth'
$array | Get-ADUser -Properties mail | Select-Object Name, Mail
```

It's also worth noting that the cmdlet **only has 1 positional parameter (`-Identity`)**, trying to bind an array via [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.3) as you're doing (`@array` instead of `$array`) will bind the first element of the array positionally to `-Identity` and then will attempt to bind the second element of the array to a parameter with `Position = 1` however there is none, causing the error you're seeing.